# Finite state space Markov chain

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes

In a finite state space Markov chain, does the existence of a stationary distribution implies the irreducibility of the Markov chain?

Remark: The stationary distribution is assumed to be positive in all entries.

Comment: No. You can have a stationary distribution concentrated on one of the communicating classes and zero on all others.

Comment: But that will imply that the stationary distribution has zero entries. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Consider two non-communicating states $0$ and $1$. Any distribution over them is stationary. But the chain is  reducible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In our stochastic processes class we always assumed that the Markov chain is irreducible. I just wonder if the converse is true. Now you gave a simple counterexample to me.